# org-mode skip to next headline?

Tags: org-mode, cycling

How can I skip to next heading in org-mode?

Say This is my org-file, pipe indicates the cursor:

```
* Top
** Apple|
** Banana
** Cherry
```

I'd like to run a command and have my cursor now be here:

```
* Top
** Apple
** Banana|
** Cherry
```

Comment: Hi Alex. Did this answer address your question?

Answer (score 11):

`org-next-item` is the built-in way to move forward in a plain list.  However, a [plain list](http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html) in `org-mode` actually looks like:

```
* here's the headline

  - An item
  - Another item
  - Another item
```

The example you give is of [headlines](http://orgmode.org/guide/Headlines.html#Headlines):

```
* Top
** Apple
** Banana
** Cherry
```

To move forward to the next headline, you can use `org-forward-heading-same-level` (default `C-c C-f`).  Also, since `org-mode` is built on top of `outline-mode`, you can also use the [outline motion commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Outline-Motion.html#Outline-Motion) such as  `outline-next-visible-heading` (default `C-c C-n`).  Note that `org-forward-heading-same-level` takes over for `outline-forward-same-level`, and there's also `outline-next-heading` that is not bound to a key combination by default.

Comment: +1 Maybe mention default bindings for the commands you list? `C-c C-f` for `org-forward-heading-same-level`, etc.

Comment: Good suggestion.  Done -- along with a link to the keybindings for `outline-mode`.

Comment: I like `org-forward-element` and `org-backward-element`.